# Как правильно написать выражение?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Institute of Fantasy-это лучшее место чтобы узнать,что такое фентэзи.

Comment: @Ярослав 98, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

("узнать" можно и проще, поэтому лучше другое слово)

Institute Of Fantasy - лучшее место, где можно понять, что такое фэнтези.

Узнать всё о фэнтези лучше всего в Институте фэнтези (в "Инститъют оф фэнтеси").

Если название организации сохранять в латинице, пишется без кавычек; если транслитерировать, то в кавычках и первое слово с большой буквы; в отдельных случаях (как здесь, если это "институт", а не условность типа веб-сайта) возможен перевод названия (без кавычек, напр. Институт Конфуция - педагогическая организация с отделениями в разных странах).